# Despote, mais dictateur. (Les Misérables)

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

> **Despote**, mais **dictateur**, despote résultant d’une république et résumant une révolution. Napoléon devint pour lui l’homme-peuple comme Jésus est l’homme-Dieu.

Y a-t-il une différence entre un dictateur et un despote ou c'est la conjonction de coordination 'mais' qui ne marque pas l'opposition dans ce contexte ?

Source: [Les Misérables/Tome 3/Livre 3/06](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables/Tome_3/Livre_3/06)

Answer (score 2):

Effectivement, despote et dictateur sont deux **synonymes**. Ces deux mots n'ont pas de grandes différences.

Dans l'exemple ci-dessus, le `mais` est principalement utilisé en tant que figure de style, afin d'amplifier cette caractéristique du personnage.

Answer (score 0):

Les définitions qui s'appliquent, celles du TLFi, sont les suivantes ;

> (TLfi) [despote](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=551534655;) B. P. ext. Quiconque **tend à s'arroger une autorité tyrannique** pour dominer un entourage auquel il impose sa volonté, sa loi.
>
> (TLfi) [dictateur](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=451264575;) Au fig. Celui, celle qui **exerce une autorité absolue** dans un **domaine particulier**.

Il n'est pas vraisemblable que la définition qui s'applique dans le cas de « dictateur » soit la suivante ;

> (TLFi) P. ext., cour. Celui qui, investi légalement ou non du pouvoir politique, l'exerce de façon autoritaire, voire tyrannique, sans avoir officiellement, en général, le titre correspondant. Dictateur militaire

Je ne crois pas qu'il ait été question de la légitimité de sa place au pouvoir ; si elle était mise en question ce ne pouvait être que par une très petite minorité. Il faut ensuite reconnaitre que Napoléon était un dictateur, généralement ; le code napoléonien est un exemple notoire de ce que l'on doit à sa personnalité  de dictateur. Donc je crois qu'il faut voir une différence dans ces deux mots : un tyran, mais quand même un guide spirituel.